# import java vs include php?

Tags: java, php

### I want to know the different between **include** in php and **import** in java

and also what is the different between two code below:

//methode 1 :

```
package anyNameOfPackage;
public class Main{
   public class Test{
       public Test(){ //all stuff }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // all stuff
   }
}
```

//methode 2 :

```
package anyNameOfPackage;
import otherPackageName.Test;
public class Main{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // all stuff
   }
}
```

---

is the method 2 (that use import) mean that the code is created between **package anyNameOfPackage** and **class Main** (like include in php) or between **class Main** and **method main()** (like method 1) ??

Im confused with this import

Comment: In StackOverflow, you should ask one question in each post. Anyway, here is the [tutorial about importing classes from packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).

Comment: hello, just read please what I say, I just want to know the different between two word include and import ...

Comment: Well, you are asking two questions: the difference between import and include, and the difference between two code snippets.

Comment: yes, how import work?? that the question

Answer (score 2):

Those two directives are completely different.

From [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> The include statement **includes and evaluates the specified file**. [emphasis mine]

There is no such mechanism in Java. What Java's `import` directive allows you to do is to make classes available to other classes.

That is, in Java, instead of writing:

```
final java.io.File file = ...;
```

you can write instead:

```
import java.io.File;

// and anywhere in the class:
final File file = ...;
```

There is no such thing as "code evaluation" in Java; it is not a scripting language. You cannot include a Java file into another Java file.

Which makes no sense anyway, since a file in Java is, by the specification, named specifically for a class, so in your classpath, class `java.io.File` will be in a file named `java/io/File.class` (which will have been compiled from a file in your source path named `java/io/File.java`).

Answer (score 0):

## Imports and namespaces

Java packages provide name spacing capabilities in Java, though they also have access semantics. Thus, a `package` declaration is generally similar to PHP's `namespace` declaration, and `import` is more or less the same as PHP `use` without `as` (it doesn't have all the capabilities of `use`, though). It has no connection whatsoever to `include`.

So, given a Java program like:

File `a/b/c/Class1.java`

```
package a.b.c;

class Class1 {}
```

The file `d/e/f/Class2.java`

```
package d.e.f;
import a.b.c.Class1;

class Class2 {
    void c2() { 
        Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
    }
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
package d.e.f;

class Class2 {
    void c2() { 
        a.b.c.Class1 obj1 = new a.b.c.Class1();
    }
}
```

Which is the same as what happen for the following PHP files:

With this `Class1.php` file:

```php
<?php
    namespace a\b\c;

    class Class1 {}
```

The `Class2.php` file:

```php
<?php
    namespace d\e\f;
    use a\b\c\Class1;

    class Class2 {

        function c2() {
            $obj1 = new Class1();
        }
    }
```

is equivalent to:

```php
<?php
    namespace d\e\f;

    class Class2 {

        function c2() {
            $obj1 = new \a\b\c\Class1();
        }
    }
```

...assuming that you have an autoload or `include`/`require` statement for the `Class1.php` file somewhere in your `auto_prepend_file`.

If it wasn't for the `import` in `Class2.java`, the compiler would think that `Class1` means `d.e.f.Class1` (unqualified file names are assumed to belong to the current package declared at the top of the compilation unit). In the same way, on the PHP side, if there was no `use` in `Class2.php`, it would assume that `Class1` refers to `\d\e\f\Class1`.

## Includes and classpath availability

The equivalent to PHP's `include`, you might say, is putting the jar file or class files in the classpath when you are running the `javac` command to compile your Java code. It's equivalent in the sense that without having an `include` or autoload (explicitly or in `auto_prepend_file`) for `Class1.php` in the above code, you'll get an error in PHP when you try to use `Class2`, and you'll get the same kind of error for the same reason if you don't put the `Class1.class` file in the classpath when you compile `Class2.java`. This is because it is looking for the actual class that fits the name `\a\b\c\Class1` or `a.b.c.Class1`, but the class implementation is not available.

But `include` and classpath availability are *not* equivalent in the sense that you can't just include code in a Java source during compilation - not through classpath, nor import, nor anything. The classpath is merely the place where the compiler is looking for the already-compiled classes that you are using in order to make sure you are using them correctly. You can't put any prints or executable statements in them.

## Summary

- `import` is more like PHP's `use`: it allows you to use a class from another package without using its fully-qualified name.
- For java to be compiled properly, the imported classes need to be available to the compiler using the class path, which in PHP is done using `include`/`require` that actually interprets the class definition.
- But PHP `include`/`require` can be used for running arbitrary code. There is no equivalent to that in Java.

## References

1. [Oracle, the Java tutorial, Using Package Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)
2. [PHP manual, Using namespaces: aliasing/importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: This part is plain wrong: "import is more like PHP's use: it allows you to use a class from another package without using its fully-qualified name." Import simply tells the Java compiler that a symbol is imported, i.e. a heads up that the symbol isn't part of the current source file being compiled. Use does something else entirely: it remaps the symbol.

Comment: @RealSkeptic butter fingered me hit 'enter' before the comment was finished. That's edited/fixed now.

Comment: @user268396 Well, `use` without `as` does not "map" really. It allows you to use the name of the class directly. See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php). So when I do `use a\b\c\Class1` it means I can use `Class1` and it refers to `a\b\c\Class1`, exactly as `import a.b.c.Class1` allows me to refer to `Class1` in Java rather than using `a.b.c.Class1`.

Comment: "Well, use without as does not "map" really." It really does: it maps the symbol 'Class1' within the scope of namespace <foo> to the name a\b\c\Class1. Note that use also permits 'relative' paths, indeed a\b\c\Class1 is relative and not a fully qualified name (there can be an outer namespace x such that a\b\c\Class1 winds up being \\x\a\b\c\Class1 ...).

Comment: More importantly without mapping the Class1 would've been assumed to be in <foo> namespace (<foo>\Class1), whereas with Java imports the name would simply refer to the class with that name in the default package (**not** the package of the source file) -- and it's entirely up to the classpath what you'll get (hopefully a compile error). So the semantics of the two are quite different, aside from aliasing with `use`.

Comment: @user268396 (1) I tested my code. It works. (2) Without mapping it would have been considered in `d\e\f` namespace, not some "foo".  (3) Note that the PHP manual specifically says that import names do not need to be stated as absolute namespaces and they are not calculated relative to the surrounding namespace. (4) In Java, if a class name is not qualified and not imported, it is expected to be in the same package that is declared at the top of the file where it is mentioned - not the "default" class. See [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Include**
`include` in php is functionally equivalent (based on the include path) to copying and pasting the source of the referenced file into the file.

**something.php**

```
<?php
echo 'hello';
?>
```

**otherthing.php**

```
<?php
include "something.php"
echo ', world!';
?>
```

otherthing.php functions identically as

```
<?php
echo 'hello';
echo ', world!';
?>
```

This means that anything that the included file does outside of defining functions, classes, and variables, will be a side effect of the `include` process seen in the including script.

**Java Import**

Is used to import a symbol into your current scope. It does not include the entire file, and it does not have output side effects.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
// use ArrayList as if it were locally defined instead of typing java.util.ArrayList
```